# Change href destination of child

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a bunch of blocks (divs) with child divs that have links (sp-pcp-readmore) I want to change the href value of every link (sp-pcp-readmore) with jQuery. The HTML for one div (block) is as follows:

```
<div class="sp-pcp-post pcp-item-4978" data-id="4978">
    <div class="pcp-post-thumb-wrapper">
        <div class="sp-pcp-post-thumb-area">
            <a
                class="sp-pcp-thumb"
                aria-label="feature_image"
                href="/machines/"
                target="_blank"
            >
                <img
                    src="machine-300x300.jpg"
                    data-src="machine-300x300.jpg"
                    class="pcp-lazyload lazy-loaded"
                    alt=""
                    width="300"
                    height="300"
                />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h2 class="sp-pcp-title">
        <a href="/machines/" target="_blank"
            >Machines</a
        >
    </h2>

    <div class="sp-pcp-post-content">
        <div class="sp-pcp-readmore">
            <a
                class="pcp-readmore-link"
                target="_blank"
                href="/machines/"
            >
                Explore Now
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The javascript I am having trouble with is this and it is not changing the href at all

```
        $(".sp-pcp-title").each(function() {
            switch($(this).text()) {
                case "Machines":
                        $(this).find(".pcp-readmore-link").attr('href', '/product-category/machines/');
                    break;
                case "Weights":
                        $(this).find(".pcp-readmore-link").attr('href', '/product-category/weights/')
                    break;
                case "Dumbells":
                        $(this).find(".pcp-readmore-link").attr('href', '/product-category/dumbells/')
                    break;
                case "Barbels":
                        $(this).find(".pcp-readmore-link").attr('href', '/product-category/barbels/')
                    break;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is changed according to your sample HTML code, the target link is not a child of `.sp-pcp-title` but next sibling inside `.sp-pcp-post-content`

```js
   $(".sp-pcp-title").each(function() {
            switch($(this).children('a').text()) {
                case "Machines":
                        $(this).next('.sp-pcp-post-content').find(".pcp-readmore-link").attr('href', '/product-category/machines/');
                    break;
                case "Weights":
                        $(this).next('.sp-pcp-post-content').find(".pcp-readmore-link").attr('href', '/product-category/weights/')
                    break;
                case "Dumbells":
                        $(this).next('.sp-pcp-post-content').find(".pcp-readmore-link").attr('href', '/product-category/dumbells/')
                    break;
                case "Barbels":
                        $(this).next('.sp-pcp-post-content').find(".pcp-readmore-link").attr('href', '/product-category/barbels/')
                    break;
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sp-pcp-post pcp-item-4978" data-id="4978">
    <div class="pcp-post-thumb-wrapper">
        <div class="sp-pcp-post-thumb-area">
            <a
                class="sp-pcp-thumb"
                aria-label="feature_image"
                href="/machines/"
                target="_blank"
            >
                <img
                    src="machine-300x300.jpg"
                    data-src="machine-300x300.jpg"
                    class="pcp-lazyload lazy-loaded"
                    alt=""
                    width="300"
                    height="300"
                />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h2 class="sp-pcp-title">
        <a href="/machines/" target="_blank"
            >Machines</a
        >
    </h2>

    <div class="sp-pcp-post-content">
        <div class="sp-pcp-readmore">
            <a
                class="pcp-readmore-link"
                target="_blank"
                href="/machines/"
            >
                Explore Now
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: very non-dry...

Answer (score 1):

This can be vastly simplified

```
$(".sp-pcp-title").each(function() {
  let text = $("a",this).text().trim();
  $(this).next().find(".pcp-readmore-link").attr('href', `/product-category/${text.toLowerCase()}`);
});
```

```js
$(".sp-pcp-title").each(function() {
  let text = $("a",this).text();
  $(this).next().find(".pcp-readmore-link").attr('href', `/product-category/${text.toLowerCase()}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sp-pcp-post pcp-item-4978" data-id="4978">
  <div class="pcp-post-thumb-wrapper">
    <div class="sp-pcp-post-thumb-area">
      <a class="sp-pcp-thumb" aria-label="feature_image" href="/machines/" target="_blank">
        <img src="machine-300x300.jpg" data-src="machine-300x300.jpg" class="pcp-lazyload lazy-loaded" alt="" width="300" height="300" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <h2 class="sp-pcp-title">
    <a href="/machines/" target="_blank">Machines</a>
  </h2>
  <div class="sp-pcp-post-content">
    <div class="sp-pcp-readmore">
      <a class="pcp-readmore-link" target="_blank" href="">Explore Now</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternative

```
const hrefs = { "Machine":"machine", "Bar- and dumbells":"weights" }
$(".sp-pcp-title").each(function() {
  let text = $("a",this).text().trim();
  $(this).next().find(".pcp-readmore-link").attr('href', `/product-category/${hrefs[text]}`);
});
```

```js
    const hrefs = { "Machines":"machines", "Bar- and dumbells":"weights" }
    $(".sp-pcp-title").each(function() {
      let text = $("a",this).text().trim();
      $(this).next().find(".pcp-readmore-link").attr('href', `/product-category/${hrefs[text]}`);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sp-pcp-post pcp-item-4978" data-id="4978">
  <div class="pcp-post-thumb-wrapper">
    <div class="sp-pcp-post-thumb-area">
      <a class="sp-pcp-thumb" aria-label="feature_image" href="/machines/" target="_blank">
        <img src="machine-300x300.jpg" data-src="machine-300x300.jpg" class="pcp-lazyload lazy-loaded" alt="" width="300" height="300" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <h2 class="sp-pcp-title">
    <a href="/weights/" target="_blank">Bar- and dumbells</a>
  </h2>
  <div class="sp-pcp-post-content">
    <div class="sp-pcp-readmore">
      <a class="pcp-readmore-link" target="_blank" href="">Explore Now</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This would be great if the links all matched the title but they don't unfortunately. Thanks for the lesson though on how to simplify it.

Comment: @calvincani See added example